# zend, how to add multiOption with numbers and text?

Tags: php, zend-framework, select, zend-form

i have a zend drop down style code:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'waistmin', array(
            'label' => 'Pants:',
            'multiOptions' => array_combine(range(21, 48), range(21, 48)),
            'value' => 21
    ));
```

this will do :

```
<select id="waistmin" name="waistmin">
<option selected="selected" label="21" value="21">21</option>
<option label="22" value="22">22</option>
.......
<option label="47" value="47">47</option>
<option label="48" value="48">48</option>
</select>
```

what i want to do is to add an `array('', 'Any')` option so the code will have the `Any` option as the first one and selected by default.

and im not sure how to add this option inside the `array_combine`

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'multiOptions' => array_merge(array(''=>'', 'Any'=>'Any'), 
                              array_combine(range(21, 48), range(21, 48))
                             )
```

Comment: cool, thanks, what about the `'value' => 21` ... if i set it to `''` it will show an empty select, i want it to show `Any`